# Label Matplotlib subplot y-axes with list of strings

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, label, axis

I'm using Matplotlib to create 2 side-by-side horizontal bar charts showing regression coefficient importance across several words. I'd like to label the y-axes with each word in the list.

Every other word is appended to the y-axis when I try this:

```
# plot word importance bar graphs
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(5,10))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 1)

axes[0].set_title('Low revenue')
axes[0].invert_yaxis()
axes[0].barh(np.arange(len(lowrev_topten)), lowrev_topten['Coefficient'])
axes[0].set_yticklabels(list(lowrev_topten['Word']))
axes[0].set_xlabel('Coefficient')

axes[1].set_title('High revenue')
axes[1].invert_yaxis()
axes[1].barh(np.arange(len(highrev_topten)), highrev_topten['Coefficient'])
axes[1].set_yticklabels(list(highrev_topten['Word']))
axes[1].set_xlabel('Coefficient')
```

[image: Every other label shows up]

However, when I remind it that I'd like to have 10 ticks for 10 words (`plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10))`), it fixes the second subplot:

```
# plot word importance bar graphs
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(5,10))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 1)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10))

axes[0].set_title('Low revenue')
axes[0].invert_yaxis()
axes[0].barh(np.arange(len(lowrev_topten)), lowrev_topten['Coefficient'])
axes[0].set_yticklabels(list(lowrev_topten['Word']))
axes[0].set_xlabel('Coefficient')

axes[1].set_title('High revenue')
axes[1].invert_yaxis()
axes[1].barh(np.arange(len(highrev_topten)), highrev_topten['Coefficient'])
axes[1].set_yticklabels(list(highrev_topten['Word']))
axes[1].set_xlabel('Coefficient')
```

[image: Now the second subplot has the proper y-tick labels]

How do I get **both subplots** to have the proper y-tick labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to `set_yticks` for each subplot.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(5,10))
...
axes[0].set_yticks(np.arange(0,10))
axes[1].set_yticks(np.arange(0,10))
```